# Is it possible to execute nested queries in S3 Select?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-s3-select

I am trying to execute a query of the type: 
`SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM s3object s WHERE ..)`

But I get the following error:
`Invalid Data Source type.`

So does S3 Select support nested queries or am I missing on something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon S3 Select doesn't support nested queries. According to [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-select.html#s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-from), Amazon S3 Select and S3 Glacier Select support the following forms of the `FROM` clause:

```
FROM table_name
FROM table_name alias
FROM table_name AS alias
```

Where `table_name` is one of `S3Object` (for Amazon S3 Select) or `ARCHIVE` or `OBJECT` (for S3 Glacier Select) referring to the archive being queried over. Users coming from traditional relational databases can think of this as a database schema that contains multiple views over a table.